# Inconsistent Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am receiving the following errors:

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined : Line 18
2. Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.LineChart is not a constructor : Line 43

The first error, I receive constantly, but everything that should load, does load. I don't know if it is a problem or not.

However, the second error is a bit weird. It is very inconsistent and causes the graph to not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Elevation Profiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap());

        function initMap() {
            var path = [
                {lat: 36.579, lng: -118.292},
                {lat: 36.24, lng: -116.832}];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: path[1],
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });

            var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
            displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);
        }

        function displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map) {
            new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                strokeColor: '#0000CC',
                strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                map: map
            });

            elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
                'path': path,
                'samples': 256
            }, plotElevation);
        }

        function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
            for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
                data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation*3.28084]);
            }

            var options = {
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'ABC Miles'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Elevation (ft)'
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'none'
                }
            };
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****API_KEY_HERE*****&callback=initMap">  
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        /* Style the header */
        header {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 35px;
        }

        /* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
        nav {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        article {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        section:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            nav, article {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="map" style="height:400px;"></div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <nav>
            <h2><center>TBD</center></h2>
        </nav>
        <article>
            <div id="elevation_chart"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`, you are already including it.
2. Add script to include maps api in `head` and rest of the execution in `body` so that it can be invoked only after maps api and DOM is ready.
3. Change `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap());` to `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap);`. You just have to specify the callback which should be invoked when google charts is done loading the libraries. `initMap()` would rather invoke the method instead.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g4yd6wfp/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Elevation Profiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> <!-- add your js api key etc in this file only -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        /* Style the header */
        header {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 35px;
        }

        /* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
        nav {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        article {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        section:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            nav, article {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="map" style="height:400px;"></div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <nav>
            <h2><center>TBD</center></h2>
        </nav>
        <article>
            <div id="elevation_chart"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <script>
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap);

        function initMap() {
            var path = [
                {lat: 36.579, lng: -118.292},
                {lat: 36.24, lng: -116.832}];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: path[1],
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });

            var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
            displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);
        }

        function displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map) {
            new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                strokeColor: '#0000CC',
                strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                map: map
            });

            elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
                'path': path,
                'samples': 256
            }, plotElevation);
        }

        function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
            for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
                data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation*3.28084]);
            }

            var options = {
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'ABC Miles'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Elevation (ft)'
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'none'
                }
            };https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843425/inconsistent-uncaught-typeerror#
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue still occurs with these changes and even occurs on fiddle.
"{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.LineChart is not a constructor",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 110,
  "colno": 25
}"

Comment: @user9675088 ah. happening in chrome, but not in firefox.

Comment: figured it out!! change `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap());` to `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap);`

Comment: @user9675088 when you pass the callback, you just have to tell the function name which should be invoked once google charts is ready with loading of the libraries, doing `initMap()` would rather invoke the function

Comment: Thanks for the catch, its working now. That is good to know. I am still a bit new to js, so it is good to know that for the future!

Comment: sure. It was fun to debug too. I completely missed it till I copied the code and ran it through my system and carefully scrutinized each line. Glad it helps you. You can accept it as answer if if fixes the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the external librairies are loaded before calling anything from them. Try wrapping your code execution with a

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    // Your code here

});
```

That might get rid of theses error you're having